# url-tag for url include

Tags: django, url, django-templates

i use [the set_language redirect view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/internationalization/#the-set-language-redirect-view) form from the docs.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
)
```

template:

```
<form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
<select name="language">
{% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
{% for language in languages %}
<option value="{{ language.code }}">{{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Which is the right syntax to replace the action attribute "/i18n/setlang/" with the url-template-tag?

EDIT:

I found the right url in the include (thanks to Daniel!):

```
<form action="{% url django.views.i18n.set_language %}" method="post">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url), you can enter the full path of a view as the `{% url %}` parameter

```
{% url django.views.i18n.set_language %} # quote or unquote based on your Django version
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't care about the URL of the include, you care about the URLs inside the include. You should look at the code or the documentation for `django.conf.urls.i18n` to find the `setlang` URL you are interested in, and use that name.